# Angular HttpClient not returning integer property with value of 0

Tags: angular, post, integer, httpclient, undefined

So when i call a .Net WebAPI built in C#, from a Nativescript + Angular + TypeScript app, using Angular HttpClient, for some reason the object returned that should contain an integer property 'UserState', doesn't have that property at all, if the value returned from the WebAPI is 0.

If that value is 1 or more, then the property 'UserState' is visible in the HttpClient response object.

I can understand that NULL properties aren't mapped into the JSON response (the same way the 'Name' property below isn't) but an Integer of 0 is still a valid property value, seems odd its acting like a NULL value.

I've done quite a bit of searching, but its a difficult thing to word into a search term and I haven't found anything that relates to this.

WebAPI - User model:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserState { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

WebAPI - System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult > Content (Displayed in json for simplicity)

```
{
    Id: 123456,
    UserState: 0,
    Name: null,
}
```

App - User Interface

```
export interface User {
    Id: number,
    UserState: number,
    Name: string,
}
```

App - HttpClient Post

```
return this.http.post<User>(url, body, { headers: headers })
```

App - Post Response (If UserState is 0)

```
{
    Id: 123456,
}
```

App - Post Response (If UserState is 1)

```
{
    Id: 123456,
    UserState: 1,
}
```

Comment: It looks like there is some issue on your backend side (the webapi) as the `UserState` isn't being sent on the json payload if zero. To be sure, did you check the responde on the network tab using Chrome Dev Tools?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are using "==" operator and not "=" operator while making comparison inside your subscribe.